why is sequence value different across different db instances in postgresql?
I am using RDS Aurora serverless for Postgresql 15 hosted by AWS. The cluster has 3 instances, one write and 2 reads. I created a sequence by SEQUENCE test START 10;. And I use select nextval(test) to increase the sequence value.
However, I found the sequence value is different when I run below command between write and read instance:
select * from test;

I wonder why the value is different. If the write instance is down and one of the read instance becomes the write, will it give me duplicate values?
I have verified the Aurora is not using logical replica:
=> show rds.logical_replication;
 rds.logical_replication
-------------------------
 off
(1 row)

AMSEngine=> SHOW wal_level;
 wal_level
-----------
 replica
(1 row)


Can you start ‘psql’ and run ‘select * from pg_stat_replication_slots’ ? I wonder what type of replication is set up

I used this as well but it gives me the same result. The read and write are different. The cluster is managed by AWS and I don't have any particular setting for replication type. I expect all data within the same cluster are synced. Is there any setting for that?

I am not very familiar with Aurora but I do know Postgres. I know this issue can happen if the replication type is logical since it does not replicate sequences, so please check the replication type so we can mark that off.

I have put more details about replica type. it doesn't use logical replica in Aurora.

If sequence value is included into a table then transaction corresponding to tables are logged in WAL along with incremental sequence value,this is the practical use of sequence objects.
If you just create a sequence object without linking to any table,the value in slave will be ahead of master,this is done to improve the performance by reducing the WAL logs related to sequence objects.WAL record is not generated for every call of nextval() function.
Also in case of failover, whatever value the slave has will be present after promotion.This will not result in duplication but you will find gaps in sequence values after failover because slave's sequence value is ahead of master's.
Refer below link:-
https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/1296642753.8673.29.camel%40gibralter
Also refer below article:-
https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/gaps-in-sequences-postgresql/

The doc says the sequence number relates to a session. Does the session mean each login? The doc doesn't say anything about write/read instances. I can see there is about 20 gaps between write and read instance always. What could happen if there is a failover on the write?

I have edited the answer go through it once.

Thanks for the explanation.  I am interesting to see slave is ahead of master. If there are hundreds call on nextval in master during a short time, will they sync to slave in time? if not, the master would be ahead of slave which causing duplicate sequence on failover?

For hundred call on nextval let say 6 WAL records are generated in master.In this case it is the job of failover script/procedure to replay all the generated 6 WAL files of master in slave without any apply lag before promotion of slave.
